# Compare two charts and get percentage of similarity

Tags: php, python, algorithm, math

**question:How to compare two chart ranges, and get percentage as a result.**

I want to compare two chart parts, (range of 60 values), and as a result get percentage of difference. So i can find very similar chart curves. 
(Example:Get all charts that are 90% similar to this one)

For every range, data is stored in 60 number array.
Every range starts with 0 and all next numbers represent chart value from that moment.("+" chart goes up and "-" chart goes down)

```
$range1 = array(0.00,-0.90,2.10,0.10,-3.40,-4.30,-1.90,-0.30,0.00,0.10,-0.60,-0.20,-0.30,-0.30,1.00,-0.90,-0.50,1.00,2.80,5.00,5.50,5.20,6.70,5.50,5.70,7.30,6.00,5.10,5.30,11.10,10.90,9.00,7.10,6.60,7.00,5.50,5.50,12.60,15.60,14.30,18.50,16.60,16.60,20.30,20.60,18.10,16.10,19.10,14.40,18.70,17.40,17.80,17.20,19.90,20.60,17.70,17.00,17.50,16.70,14.70);
$range2 = array(0.00,-2.90,-3.60,-3.10,-3.90,-5.90,-11.80,-8.40,-8.00,-8.40,-8.20,-7.00,-7.60,-7.30,-5.10,-7.20,-7.30,-7.40,-7.70,-8.90,-9.30,-9.30,-9.90,-7.50,-11.70,-12.20,-19.80,-19.60,-19.90,-19.00,-22.10,-19.10,-20.10,-18.90,-19.70,-19.90,-16.50,-23.70,-26.60,-24.20,-28.30,-27.00,-28.60,-28.90,-22.90,-24.00,-25.10,-24.30,-18.40,-31.70,-29.80,-29.00,-29.50,-28.30,-35.50,-27.60,-34.00,-32.80,-36.00,-34.40,);


$result = some_specific_manual_written_function($range1, $range2);

//as a result i want get percentage or something else from what i can how similar charts are
```

I will do it reading csv files and then storing it to db, so it can be done with php or python.

Comment: How do you define "90% similar" in mathematical terms and what have you tried so far?

Comment: You are looking for correlation coefficient between two datasets this is first relevant hit in google: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Statistics2/correlation.htm so you get +1 for match 0 for no similarity and -1 for oposite match ... I hope you know how to convert this to percentage :)

Comment: @Spektre thanx for link, that is new term for me so i will have a look.

Comment: @KlausD.I tried use diff in percentage for each number, and use average of all percentages, but problem is that when first part of chart is very negative and next is positive, it will be the same as first part of chart is positive and second part is negative.

Comment: It really depends on what exactly you are trying to do, but I'd start with [MSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) to measure the distance between one range to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function some_specific_manual_written_function($range1, $range2)
{
    $match = 0;
    for($i=0; count($range1); $i++)
    {
        if(in_array($range[$i],$range2))
        {
            $match++;               
        }
    }

    $percentage_match = (count($range1)/$match ) * 100;

    echo "Perncetage Match is : ".$percentage_match."%";

    return $percentage_match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function similiar($range1, $range2) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($range1 as $k => $v) {
        if ($range2[$k] == $v) {
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $return ($i/count($range1))*100);
}
```